# Realm creation and population sequence

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to build up a Realm of a bunch of data. This wouldn't be a problem but I've hit a wall - a gap in experience shall we say.

Creating one record is fine. However, one of the fields of that record is an array (`<List>`) of records from another table. Now my 2 questions are:

1. Does Realm support that? A list or array of Objects as one of the fields for a record... Answering no here will leed me on to an answer of my question - I will simply need to make an array of "primary keys" and query with those when I need to. If the answer is yes, proceed to question 2.
2. How would I go about creating those lists, bearing in mind that those tables might be created at a fraction of a second later than the current one, meaning those records don't yet exist and therefore can't be added to the list...

Example:

```
class baseRLMObject: Object {
// Creates an id used as the primary key. Also includes a few methods.
}
class Film: baseRLMObject {
  var name: String!
  var episodeId: Int!
  var characters = List<Character>()
}
class Character: baseRLMObject {
  var name: String!
  var films = List<Film>()
}
```

See how all the film objects need to be created first before the character objects? Otherwise I could try add a film which does not yet exist and then it all crashes and burns :( Reason I want to try find a better way is, I'm dealing with 10 tables, a few hundred records and variable connection speeds. It would be too long to wait for each data retrieval to finish before the next one starts. AND since they are all suffering from the same problem (inter-connections), regardless of which I start with, it won't work...

Thank you :)

Comment: try read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276659/realm-swift-many-to-many-relationship), see if it can help u, many-to-many relationship in Realm can be use with `Inverse Relationships`

Comment: Thanks @Tj3n.. While this taught me something, that problem still has the benefit of having the objects available when a list is created. I'm stuck with the problem of 1 object trying to add another object to it's list - but the object it's trying to add has not been created yet. What then? haha

Comment: I dont really understand that issue of yours, you can totally just create it without some property, if i understand correctly, your API return with the name list for film/character, then just create corresponding film/character without other property

Comment: API is called and returns data. Data starts getting processed into Realm. Table "Films" is created and in the first record, it tries to add the Character (or rather a relationship to the Character with primary key 5) to the list of characters (one of the fields. like name, length etc). Problem is, Character5 hasn't been created yet so nothing can be added to the list... This problem happens with every single table I have so there is no starting point for a waterfall type approach.

Comment: Then create the Character 5 with that id but without name/age/etc...? I think it will be fine?

Comment: Yes that solved most of the problem (Thanks :) ) and your inverse suggestion I think will solve the rest... Thank you :) Put it in an answer so I can accept it

Comment: sure :D glads to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, for the object that haven't been created, you should create an empty object with only the primary key, then re-fetch and add value after the other network request called

For Many-to-many relationship, you can use Realm's [Inverse Relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships) to create linking between these objects like:

```
class Character: baseRLMObject {
  var name: String!
  var films = LinkingObjects(fromType: Film.self, property: "characters")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like it's being discussed in the comments, you should be able to use Realm's [inverse relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships) feature to automate most of this process:

```
class baseRLMObject: Object {
// Creates an id used as the primary key. Also includes a few methods.
}
class Film: baseRLMObject {
  var name: String!
  var episodeId: Int!
  var characters = List<Character>()
}
class Character: baseRLMObject {
  var name: String!
  let films = LinkingObjects(fromType: Film.self, property: "characters")
}
```

When calling `character.films`, a `List` will be returned of all of the `Film` objects whose `characters` property contains that object.

This is a lot easier and error-free than trying to maintain two separate relational lists between object types.